# PostgreSQL showing data report by last twelve month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query in postgresql where i want to make report based on last 12 month. Even if there is no record inserted in a specific month, I want to show the result 0 for that specific month. Here is  my result so far:

```
Select count(A.id),date_part('month',request_date),
count(*) FILTER (WHERE is_inbound =false) AS inbound,
count(*) FILTER (WHERE is_inbound =true) AS outbound
from
lead_generation_history AS A
 WHERE  request_date > (current_date - INTERVAL '12 months')
GROUP BY  date_part('month',request_date);
```

This is the result i am getting:

```
 Date_part   Inbound  Outbound
    10            1       1
    11            3       4
```

But  i want to show the data of last 12 month with month name even if there is no record. This is my expected result:

```
 Date_part   Inbound  Outbound
  January      0        0       
  February     0        0
```

This way i want to list all 12 month data.How can i do it?

Comment: you need rearray data with back side language after to getting it from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a table of the last 12 months using `generate_series` (I call it `lm`)
2. `left join` table `lm` with `lead_generation_history` on month of `request_date`
3. use your query slightly modified

```sql
with lm(running_month) as 
(
 select generate_series(date_trunc('month', current_date) - '11 months'::interval, date_trunc('month', current_date), '1 month'::interval)
)
select 
  to_char(lm.running_month, 'month')
  count(A.id),
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE not is_inbound) AS inbound,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE is_inbound) AS outbound
from
  lm left outer join lead_generation_history AS A 
  on lm.running_month = date_trunc('month', request_date)
GROUP BY lm.running_month;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I had another query. If I want to take short form of a month like Jan,Feb .what i need to do?

Comment: Use `to_char(lm.running_month, 'Mon')`.  Here is the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) about formatting.